# Trying to send POST request as Json via javax.ws.rs. org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.<init> Exception

Tags: json, exception, post, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to send POST request in Json format to server - it is Json Object, GameState class instance. For this purpose I want to use Jersey - java.ws.rs Library.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8081/hello").path("game")
.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.post(Entity.json(Game.getInstance().getGameState()), Response.class);
```

`Entity.json(Game.getInstance().getGameState()).getEntity()`

in my case has the following value:

```
GameState(type=DOUBLEBOARD, side=WHITE, piecesOnBoardSer=Board.logic.GameState$PiecesOnBoardSer@22fa5204, piecesBeyondBoardSer=Board.logic.GameState$PiecesBeyondBoardSer@588247fc, id=null)
```

So it is Json Object with GameState

Some dependencies specified in build.gradle:

```
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'jakarta.ws.rs', name: 'jakarta.ws.rs-api', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1'
    implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-core:3.5.3'
}
```

Exception if try to run (part of):

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.<init>(Ljakarta/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.<init>(ClientConfig.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.<init>(ClientConfig.java:503)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder.<init>(JerseyClientBuilder.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:116)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:206)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
    at Board.logic.Game$SendStateSupplier.handle(Game.java:193)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at Board.logic.Game.setGameState(Game.java:138)
    at Board.logic.Game.handleChanges(Game.java:148)
    at Board.javafx.Impl3D.Actions.MovePiece.handle(MovePiece.java:58)
    at Board.javafx.Impl3D.Actions.MovePiece.handle(MovePiece.java:12)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3602)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3906)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
```

Comment: Posting a partial stack trace with no error message, it hardly sufficient. Please post the entire trace w/error message

Comment: @PaulSamsotha updated, thank you for your comment. Really appreciate if you can help

Comment: Why do you have two different versions of JAX-RS dependency? And make sure nothing else you have is pulling in a different version of Jersey. Whenever you see a NoSuchMethodError, it's almost always a problem with conflicting dependency versions. Make sure _all_ your Jersey jars are the same version. Look at all the Jars your dependencies are pulling in.